# connect a new identifier in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys

I have a table called Users that has the identifier called IdUser that is INT and AI.
I have another table called Subscription that has the foreign key called IdUser that is connected with the primary key of the table Users.

Now, the problem that I have is:
If when I insert a row in the table Users I would like to insert also a row in the subscription table, how can I do?

```
insert into users (nome, cognome, ...) values ('x', 'y', ...)
insert into subscription (...,IdUser) values (..., ????)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's your problem? You just need these two insert queries and you're done.

Comment: @Chris But I don't know what IDUser insert in the second query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mysql

```
insert into users (nome, cognome, ...) values ('x', 'y', ...);
insert into subscription (...,IdUser) values (...,LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

see
    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL with PHP (which you shouldn't: [MySQL is depcrecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php))

```
mysql_query("insert into users (nome, cognome, ...) values ('x', 'y', ...)
");
$userID = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("insert into subscription (...,IdUser) values (..., ".$userID.")");
```